# Append semicolon on pressing enter key in asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, .net, dom-events

How to add a semicolon to the text in asp.net text box (web application), on pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> and move the cursor to next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using pure JavaScript.

HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DemoTextBox" runat="server" 
        CssClass="textarea"
        TextMode="MultiLine"/>
```

Code Behind (onclick javascript event wire up)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DemoTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "AppendSemiColon(this, event)");
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
function AppendSemiColon(objTextBox, evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        objTextBox.value += ";";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried ur code and its not working, im getting error object required. txtActionTaken.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "AppendSemicolon(this,event)"); <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> debugger; function AppendSemiColon(objTextBox, evt) { var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode if (charCode == 13) { objTextBox.value += ";"; } } </script>

Comment: Hi can u please help solving this

Comment: i checked the code and every thing is fine but its not working, i am gettin this error object required. can u tell me wts causing error.

Comment: The problem is that the control is in tabcontainer and the java script is not able to find the id of the control so i repalced the id 'txtActionTaken' as TabContainer1_TabPanel3_txtActionTaken and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the `keypress` event in JavaScript and check which key it was.  The key code for "enter" is 13.  So if they press enter, append a semi-colon and return.  Something like this:

**Edit:** (a more complete example to include the ASP.NET markup, etc.)

```
<!-- page headers, other markup, etc. -->
<asp:TextBox ID="txtActiontaken" runat="server" />
<!-- other markup, the rest of the page, etc. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<%=txtActiontaken.ClientID%>').keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        // append a semi-colon to the control's value
        $('#<%=txtActiontaken.ClientID%>').val($(' <%=txtActiontaken.ClientID%>').val()+';');
      }
      return true;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: where to copy this code in appn..can u tell me with an example.

Comment: can you please tell me how to access the above code in asp.net web application. its helpful if there is an example.

Comment: @Uneverno: This is JavaScript code (specifically making use of the jQuery library, since that's common enough to assume these days), so it would go on the page itself.  You'd probably want to put it at the bottom of the page and wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` to make sure it doesn't run until the DOM loads.  You did tag the question with the `JavaScript` tag, so I assume you know what I'm saying, right?

Comment: i still dont get how to access the code..pls bear with me..i tried as below in source page****$(document).ready(function(e){   if(e.keyCode == 13) {  $('txtActiontaken').val($('txtActiontaken').val()+';');   }   return true; });**** In code file, i caled the function as below*** txtActionTaken.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "function(event)");*** ..is dis correct..

Comment: @Uneverno: You don't have to put anything in the C# code file.  This is entirely a client-side operation. All you need is to have the jQuery library included in your pages and then just add that JavaScript code to the page in question. The only thing you'd need to change is that you may need to replace `txtActiontaken` with `<%=txtActiontaken.ClientID%>` since that identifier is probably server-side and the JavaScript will need the client-side identifier. Also, don't forget the `#` before it in the jQuery selector (as in my example). If you Google jQuery you can find lots of docs and examples.

Comment: @Uneverno: I've updated my answer to include more of the surrounding markup to show you where this would go on an ASP.NET page and how it would interact with the text box.  But I urge you not to just copy/paste code you find on the internet (even on Stack Overflow) and to take the time to research and understand what that code is doing.  This particular one is a key example of separation of server-side code and client-side code and is really worth learning.  One can not be a web developer on ASP.NET alone, understanding HTML/JavaScript/CSS are very important.